# VLCj: How to set motion blur?

Tags: java, vlc, vlcj, motion-blur

I am developing an interactive video player and would like to dynamically set motion blur using VLCj 3.0.1. Since `EmbeddedMediaPlayer` doesn't provide some kind of `setBlur` method, I guess I am supposed to use `addMediaOptions(String... options)`.

However, I haven't been able to figure out how to use it. Starting VLC from the command line I would have to add the following parameters `--video-filter=motionblur blur-factor=44`. Providing the same parameter in an array, doesn't show any effect though. I would be glad, if someone could show me the correct syntax. This is essentially my code:

```
EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent vlc = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
EmbeddedMediaPlayer player = vlc.getMediaPlayer(); 
player.playMedia(path); 

String[] options = { "video-filter=motionblur", "blur-factor=" + blur }; 
player.addMediaOptions(options);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example code you are adding options *after* you play the media, that might work in some instances but you should really (generally) just pass them in as additional parameters on your `playMedia` call.

However...

Some of those options that are not directly supported by a LibVLC API function must be passed when you create the LibVLC instance (i.e. the vlcj `MediaPlayerFactory`) rather than when you play media.

Since you are using `EmeddedMediaPlayerComponent` then you should subclass your `EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent` and override `onGetMediaPlayerFactoryArgs()` and pass your motion blur options, along with whatever else you need, there.

Note that you need to send the exact command-line switches, so you must prefix your options with "--".

There is an example of doing precisely that in the vlcj Javadoc for `EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent`.

People often ask is there any documentation describing how each of the available VLC options can be set - the short answer is no there is not, and that any use of options like this is totally unsupported and may not work with a future version of VLC/LibVLC.

Ideally, enabling motion blur would be achievable by a new LibVLC API function, but someone would have to write a patch for VLC to make that happen.

Comment: By overriding `onGetMediaPlayerFactoryArgs` I am now able to initially set a blur factor. However, depending on user input, I would like to dynamically change blur factor after starting a video. Do I understand you correctly, that I would have to create a new `EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent`?

Comment: Most likely, yes, you will have to create a new component each time with different arguments. It *might* be the case that you can enable the filter via the factory args, and then later pass options via playMedia(mrl, options) for the actual blur factor - I don't know for sure, you'll have to try it - if that works, then you can just use the same EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent

Comment: The best solution is to patch VLC/LibVLC to expose the filter via an API of course, but that is a whole other problem.